# Magento 2 : JS issue at the time of enable bundle js

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento-2.0.7, fotorama

I am trying to enable bundle js feature but getting this issue on product view page

> SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
>   `</div>'}}(window,document,location,"undefined"!`

Any one have idea about this issue of fotoram.min.js or fotoram.js

Comment: Can you post the code where you write something like above.

Comment: its a default magento code of file `lib/web/fotorama/fotorama.js`.